# How to customise the color of leader line (line that connects graph and label) in a pie chart (Amcharts v4)

Tags: angular, graph, pie-chart, amcharts, amcharts4

I made a pie chart using amcharts v4. The background color of the div containing the pie chart is a dark color and the leader line (the line that connects the graph and the label) is by default a dark color which makes it invisible.

[Pie chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebuw6.png)

Is there any way to customise the color of the leader line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Tick

```
pieSeries.ticks.template.stroke = '#d0d2d6';
pieSeries.ticks.template.strokeWidth = 1;
```